# Why this JS code doesn't work on altervista?

Tags: javascript

The issue is simple: on jsfiddle work perfectly, not on altervista.

```
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
 var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

 box.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('pause');
   if (audio.paused) {     
      audio.play();
   } else {
      audio.pause();
   }
 });
```

to try it: https://jsfiddle.net/rezt5und/2/

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, it doesn't matter where it comes from.

Comment: Do you have a link to the altervista page where it doesn't work?

Comment: @Barman yes! http://riseofrome.altervista.org/provahomepage.html

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a good question. What is it supposed to do, what is it doing wrong?

Comment: I tryied to change the position of the script. Everywhere, doesn't work

Comment: @Barman when I click on button on site sound stil going on and button desn't toggle

Comment: compare site and jsfiddle

Comment: You have lots of other HTML on the altervista site. I think something may be overlaying the `.box` element so the click event doesn't get to it.